# How can I remove the block "stock status" from product page via xml?

Tags: layout, local.xml

I need to remove a block which is called in catalog.xml:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

I tried it in my own local.xml with following code. But both don't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
<reference name="product.info">
<remove name="product.info.simple"/>
</reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
</layout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info">
<remove name="product.info.simple"/>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why is the code duplicated?

Comment: Why is there two snippets in the file?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to write layout xml for this as it is available

```
Magento->admin->Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory
```

Simply set Display Products Availability in Stock on Storefront to No.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout>
        <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
            <reference name="product.info">
                <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.simple</name></action>
            </reference>
        </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    </layout>
```

with reference to this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937018/magento-remove-block-using-update-xml

Answer (score 0):

Comment this code in your `catalog.xml`

```
         <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
        </reference>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't want to overwrite the theme but if its the only possibility I'm gonna do that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a downloadable product, you need to add the following to your layout XML:

```
<remove name="product.info.downloadable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Just add this code in your **catalog_product_view.xml** inside **body** tag. Your stock availability will remove from product details page.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.simple.extra.catalog_inventory_stockqty_default" remove="true"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can disabled it from admin Store -> Configuration, under Inventory section at 'Display Products Availability in Stock on Storefront' set no.